# String before logical operator wont display in alert()

Tags: javascript

If I execute this:

```
alert( "Is 4 equal to 5 ? lets see " + 4 == 5 )
```

It displays the logical value as false, but the former string "Is 4 equal to 5 ? lets see" is **missing** , can anyone explain why is this so?

Comment: Order of Operations. There is an order to the madness just like when you do equations in math.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Execution will happen line this:

```
"Is 4 equal to 5 ? lets see " + 4 // "Is 4 equal to 5 ? lets see 4"
"Is 4 equal to 5 ? lets see 4" == 5 // false
alert(false);
```

What you want is:

```
"Is 4 equal to 5 ? lets see " + (4 == 5)
```

Which will evaluate like this:

```
4 == 5 // false
"Is 4 equal to 5 ? lets see " + false
alert("Is 4 equal to 5 ? lets see false")
```

Comment: If you want the text and false to show, store the result of the comparison in a variable like `var result = 4==5;` and then `alert("Is 4 equal to 5 ? Lets see " + result);`

Comment: Ahh i now see , this was also the cause of sometime displaying wrong boolean value solved that too

Comment: That's the reason `1 + 2 == 3` doesn't give you `1 + false` / `NaN`

Answer (score 3):

Your input will be compared as,

```
"Is 4 equal to 5 ? lets see 4" == 5
```

Wrap the number comparison part into a parenthesis,

```
alert("Is 4 equal to 5 ? lets see " + (4 == 5));
```

And why this is happening in your case?

> Because `+` is having higher priority than `==` comparison operator in
>   the [table of precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). So `+` part is evaluated and then got
>   compared with the number.

And why does parenthesis make a difference?

> `()` grouping is having highest priority, hence it will be evaluated
>   first. Hence the expressions inside of it will also be evaluated.